# Is firewall only works on listening socket not on established one?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

Suppose port 80 is opened in firewall from A node to B node but how data is transfered to node B to node A on random port, Is firewall only works on listening socket not on established one?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about Linux/networking configuration. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Research "stateful firewall". Basically the firewall can be configured to recognise traffic from established connections.